# Do Democrats and Republicans still agree on what kinds of immigrants should be admitted?

Tags: united-states, immigration, public-opinion

In a [highly cited 2015 paper](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ejhain/Paper/AJPS2015c.pdf), Hainmueller and Hopkins find that "beneath partisan divisions over immigration lies a broad consensus about who should be admitted to the country."

For example, educated immigrants in high status jobs are viewed favorably, whereas those who lack plans to work, entered without authorization, or do not speak English are viewed  unfavorably.

Is there a more recent poll/data on whether this consensus survived Trump's elections?

Comment: It doubt it was true then, and I don't think it is true now. The "broad consensus" is, I think largely illusory and a product of generous interpretation of the results and phrasing of the way the issue was posed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This Adida et al. (2019) paper](https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0222504) used the same design as Hainmueller and Hopkins (conjoint experiment) for Syrian refugees and their study was in the field during Oct. - Nov. 2016. Compare that to the 2011-2012 sample from Hainmueller and Hopkins (publishing results can take a while). I was unable to find a conjoint experiment for immigration attitudes more recent than fall 2016. Of course, it is possible that if Trump affected what Republicans and Democrats value in potential immigrants (in this case, asylum-seekers) then we would see the effects by then after more than a year of campaigning for president.

As one would expect, they find that Republicans are much less interested in granting asylum than Democrats. However, it seems that Democrats and Republicans similarly value the ability to speak English, certain professions, sex, and religion. For instance, both Democrats and Republicans prefer Christian asylum-seekers to Muslim ones. Generally, what Democrats prefer Republicans also prefer, even if the absolute levels of support are very different across party (Fig. 9). Said another way, their results suggest that Democrats and Republicans disagree about how many immigrants (asylum-seekers) should be admitted --- but if they had to choose they would probably rank the potential immigrants similarly.